# Asynchronous connection not working after first failure

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, iasyncresult

I am dealing with quite annoying issue, and I could not find any solution for this.

I am calling WebRequest Connection, working under Unity C#;

```
IAsyncResult startingTheCall =  webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new      AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), parameters);
```

It sends call to server running on Windows; All works fine. But, if server is not turned off, connection waits for the response for eternity. So solve this, I add timeout:

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(startingTheCall.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallbackOfFirstStream), parameters, 10000, true);
```

Timeout works fine too; The problem is, if I ever trigger the time out (by shutting the server down), then enabled server again, BeginGetRequestStream will never reach server no matter what, until I restart the application.

I thought, that maybe on failure, I am not cleaning connections properly. So I did set up this cleaning routine inside timeout:

```
        ArrayList unbox = (ArrayList)state;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)unbox[1];
        IAsyncResult asynchronousResult = (IAsyncResult)unbox[6];
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        postStream.Close();
        request.Abort();
```

I abort the request, close the stream. Still, after 1st failure, the server will never sent responses or get the stream messages, until I restart the application. Like it is completely blocked.

Anyone ever had this behaviour?

Comment: What .NET version is this? These are super old obsolete APIs.

Comment: Unity uses NET 2.0, has some functions from 3.5 partially; Is there some fresh solution I could look at?

Comment: Uh, .NET 2.0... How many of these HTTP calls will be pending at each given time at a maximum? A few? Why can't you use super simple synchronous IO?

Comment: Yes, several of them might be pending at once, but this issues reproduced even for single connection query. Synchronous IO caused visible lags in application during problematic connection times, so I was asked by the client to switch to asynchronous. I am keeping track of all IAsyncResult in List, and in case of failure, I clean up every connection properly. Still, after the 1st failure, this stucking happens. If only I new, what is wrong.

Comment: How many of these HTTP calls will be pending at each given time at a maximum? You could switch to synchronous IO on threads which is much simpler.